# How to merge functionalities in Django Admin Mixins?

Tags: python, django

I am using two Django plugins, `django-import-export` and `django-safedelete`. Both have provided features in Django Admin dropdown. Like:

**django-import-export**
[image]

**django-safedelete**
[image]

Is there a simple method to combine features from these two plugin, with minimal code changes?

**edit** Added code

`admin.py`

```
from safedelete.admin import SafeDeleteAdmin
from import_export.admin import ExportActionMixin

class SiteEntityAdmin(ExportActionMixin, SafeDeleteAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'identifier')
```

The inheritance order of `ExportActionMixin` and `SafeDeleteAdmin` decides which dropdown option appears.

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your current `Admin`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added admin.py code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I followed the advice on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because the [**`ExportActionMixin`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/admin.py#L524-L574) defines the list of actions as:

> ```
> class ExportActionMixin(ExportMixin):
>
>     # …
>
>     actions = admin.ModelAdmin.actions + [export_admin_action]
> ```

Here it thus does not take actions of the baseclass into account.

You can fix this with:

```
from safedelete.admin import SafeDeleteAdmin
from import_export.admin import ExportActionMixin

class SiteEntityAdmin(ExportActionMixin, SafeDeleteAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'identifier')
    actions = (*ExportActionMixin.actions, *SafeDeleteAdmin.actions)
```

Comment: Got this error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: However, this worked `actions = (*ExportActionMixin.actions, *SafeDeleteAdmin.actions)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the admin actions by directly calling the actions from modules. Revised code:

```
from safedelete.admin import SafeDeleteAdmin
from import_export.admin import ExportActionMixin

class SiteEntityAdmin(ExportActionMixin, SafeDeleteAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'identifier')

    actions = [ExportActionMixin.export_admin_action, SafeDeleteAdmin.undelete_selected]
```